# Jackrabbit Persistence Manager - relevance of externalBLOBs attribute

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

What is the relevance of the `externalBLOBs` attribute in Jackrabbit's PersistenceManager class? We are running Jackrabbit 1.6.4 on Oracle using the `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.OraclePersistenceManager` class. For clustering, we are using the `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.OracleDatabaseJournal` and the `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore` with a shared location.

The cluster is working, but I want to make sure we optimize it for performance.

Should we change the value of the `externalBLOBs` attribute in this setting? The default value is `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DataStore](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore) replaced the externalBLOB feature. If you are using the data store, you can and should disable this option.

For improved performance, you should upgrade to Jackrabbit 2.x. If you can't upgrade what is the reason?

Comment: Since we are already using the DataStore, do I still need to change the value of `externalBLOBs`? What is the meaning of this attribute?

Comment: I just checked the 1.6.4 source code and noticed that the `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.OraclePersistenceManager` is setting the `externalBLOBs` value to `false` anyway. Upgrading to 2.x is planned at some point, but not at the moment.